# $\rm\LaTeX$ Preview While Editing Tag Wikis from Chromium-Based Browsers

Tags: bug, mathjax, tag-wikis

I've edited a few tag wikis, and I have found that the $\rm\LaTeX$ preview is quite spotty in Chromium-based browsers such as Chrome and Vivaldi. Most of the time, the equations in the tag wiki don't render at all. In Safari or Firefox they render just fine. This is not an issue with questions and answers, just tag wikis. It is a problem on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Can anyone else confirm this issue?

Comment: I've noticed the same thing earlier today.